# Can I send a custom Error message from server to client GRPC?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have created a simple GRPC server and  client .

What i want to do is to create a custom error in the server and pass it to the client. My code looks as follows:

**Server.js**

```
var error = require('error');

var PROTO_PATH = grpc.load(__dirname + '/proto/hello.proto');
var hello_proto = PROTO_PATH.hello;

function sayHello(call, callback) {

    try {
        var jsErr = new Error('MY_ERROR');
        jsErr.newStatus = 401;
        jsErr.newMessage = 'custom unAuthorized error';
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jsErr));
        console.log(jsErr);
        callback(jsErr);

    } catch(e) {
        callback(e);
    }
}

function sayHelloAgain(call, callback) {
    callback(null, {message: 'Hello Again ' + call.request.name});
}

function main() {

    var server = new grpc.Server();
    server.addProtoService(hello_proto.Hello.service, {sayHello: sayHello,sayHelloAgain: sayHelloAgain });
    server.bind('0.0.0.0:50051', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
    server.start();
}

main();
```

**Client.js**

```
var grpc = require('grpc');

var PROTO_PATH = grpc.load(__dirname + '/proto/hello.proto');
var hello_proto = PROTO_PATH.hello;

function main() {
    var client = new hello_proto.Hello('localhost:50051',grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
    var user;
    if (process.argv.length >= 3) {
        user = process.argv[2];
    } else {
        user = 'world';
    }

    client.sayHello({name: user}, function(err, response) {

        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err));
        console.log(err);
    });
}

main();
```

and my proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

package hello;

service Hello {
    rpc sayHello(sayHelloRequest) returns (sayHelloResponse) {}
    rpc sayHelloAgain(sayHelloRequest) returns (sayHelloResponse) {}
}


message sayHelloRequest {
    string name = 1;
}

message sayHelloResponse {
    string message = 1;
}
```

when i run the cient the result from each looks like this

Server .

```
[ 'stack', 'message', 'newStatus', 'newMessage' ]
{ [Error: MY_ERROR] newStatus: 401, newMessage: 'custom unAutorized error' }
```

Client .

```
[ 'stack', 'message', 'code', 'metadata' ]
{ [Error: MY_ERROR] code: 2, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
```

So my created custom javascript error's `newStatus, newMessage` properties have removed and it has converted to GRPC standard error message .

My Questions are

1. Is it possible to send a custom message to client ?
2. Can i create a GRPC error , not a javascript error ?
3. one way to send custom attributes to client is i think is add the custom data to `Metadata` . but i am also not sure how to do it .

Answer (score 10):

There is a helpful reply to this same question on the gRPC Google Group:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/grpc-io/X_bUx3T8S7s/x38FU429CgAJ

> You can send a custom status message to the client using the Error
>   object's message property. In your example, that is "MY_ERROR". The
>   status code should be in the "code" property, just like how you see it
>   on the client side.
>
> If you want to use the gRPC status structure instead of a JavaScript
>   error, you can do so by populating the "code" property and the
>   "message" or "details" property of the object.
>
> If you want to send metadata, you should construct an instance of the
>   grpc.Metadata class, then add key/value pairs to the resulting object.
>   Then you can pass it as the third argument of the callback or set the
>   error's "metadata" property to send it to the client with the error.
>
> Please note that the status codes that gRPC uses are not HTTP status
>   codes, but gRPC specific codes that are defined in grpc.status. You
>   should only set the error's code property using those codes. If you
>   want to send your own codes, use metadata instead.

I'll illustrate what's written above with some examples.

To send a custom message with the error, construct an `Error` with the message. This sets the `message` property:

```
var jsErr = new Error('Unauthorized');
```

As mentioned above, it's probably not useful to directly set gRPC status codes in your case. But, for reference, the gRPC status code can be set through the error's `code` property:

```
jsErr.code = grpc.status.PERMISSION_DENIED;
```

To send your own error codes, or other information, use metadata:

```
var metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
metadata.set('key1', 'value2');
metadata.set('key2', 'value2');

jsErr.metadata = metadata;
```

Now, if the server constructs the error as above and the client outputs the returned error with:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err));
console.log(err);
console.log(err.metadata);
```

then the client output is:

```
[ 'stack', 'message', 'code', 'metadata' ]
{ [Error: Unauthorized]
  code: 7,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: { key1: [Object], key2: [Object] } } }
Metadata { _internal_repr: { key1: [ 'value2' ], key2: [ 'value2' ] } }
```

Comment: Actually that question is also asked by me :D . i thought there would be more ways . anyway thank you very much for your answer (Y)

Answer (score 1):

1.Yes 2.Maybe

Avoid sending special objects (like `new Error`) over the wire. Send simple object with an error property and look for its value on the other end. See http://json.org/ to have an overview of easy transferable data.

inside Server.js try

```
function sayHello(call, callback) {

    try {
        var myCustomError = {};
        myCustomError.newStatus = 401;
        myCustomError.newMessage = 'custom unAuthorized error';
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myCustomError ));
        console.log(myCustomError);
        callback(null, {error: myCustomError, message: ""});

    } catch(e) {
        callback(e);
    }
}
```

inside the Client.js

```
client.sayHello({name: user}, function(err, response) {
    var myCustomError= response.error;
    if (myCustomError) {
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myCustomError));
        console.log(myCustomError);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hm i can understand this . but I want to send my error in the first parameter , as an Error Object , in your example you are passing it in the 2 Nd parameter and it is not an Error object  .

Answer (score 0):

According to definition of `ServerErrorResponse`, which you can return as the first parameter in your `callback`, you can create simple function for this (TypeScript).

```
function grpcError(): ServerErrorResponse {
    return {
        message: 'Something wrong', // required param
        name: 'Error',              // required param
        code: Status.UNKNOWN,       // code: 2
        metadata: undefined,
        details: undefined,
        stack: undefined,
     };
};
```

`Status` is enum from 0 to 16

```
export declare enum Status {
    OK = 0,
    CANCELLED = 1,
    UNKNOWN = 2,
    INVALID_ARGUMENT = 3,
    DEADLINE_EXCEEDED = 4,
    NOT_FOUND = 5,
    ALREADY_EXISTS = 6,
    PERMISSION_DENIED = 7,
    RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED = 8,
    FAILED_PRECONDITION = 9,
    ABORTED = 10,
    OUT_OF_RANGE = 11,
    UNIMPLEMENTED = 12,
    INTERNAL = 13,
    UNAVAILABLE = 14,
    DATA_LOSS = 15,
    UNAUTHENTICATED = 16
}
```

So the example code for server is

```
let error = grpcError();
error.message = "YOUR CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE";
callback(error, null);
```

And for client

```
client.sayHello({name: user}, function(err, response) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Output would be similar to

```
Error: 2 UNKNOWN: YOUR CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE
// stacktrace
{
  code: 2,
  details: 'YOUR CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
}
```