# Node gRPC: sending metadata from server to client without error

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc, grpc-node

From the client side, it is easy to add metadata for the server:

```
const meta = new grpc.Metadata();
meta.add('xyz', 'okay');

stub.service.Rpc(request, meta, (err, response) => {
});
```

The above can be accessed on the server like this:

```
call.metadata.get('xyz');
```

Now, if we need to send metadata **from the server to the client**, we do this:

```
const err = { code, details };
const meta = new grpc.Metadata();
meta.add('...', '...');

callback(err, null, meta);
```

Note that we are passing error, and the actual response is `null`.

How do I pass a `null` error and a non-null response, along with metadata?

If I do the following, it does not seem to work as there is no way to access the metadata on the client without the error.

```
callback(null, r, meta);
// `r` is some response message
```

***Does gRPC spec explicitly disallow sending metadata from server to client when there is no error?***

Also, while we're at it, I'd like someone explain how do we send trailing vs initial metadata from server to client in Node.

Relevant links:

- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node
- [Can I send a custom Error message from server to client GRPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777189/can-i-send-a-custom-error-message-from-server-to-client-grpc)
- [How to add metadata to nodejs grpc call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526077/how-to-add-metadata-to-nodejs-grpc-call)
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9053
- https://medium.com/compli-engineering/grpc-nodejs-using-jwt-authentication-b048fef6ecb2

Answer (score 2):

[ServerUnaryCall.sendMetadata(responseMetadata)](https://grpc.io/grpc/node/grpc-ServerUnaryCall.html#sendMetadata__anchor)

server:

```
const method = (call, cb) => {
  // code
  call.sendMetadata(metadata)
  // code
}
```

client:

```
const call = client.method(params, cb)
call.on('metadata', (metadata) => {
  // code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use such code:

```
client.someFunction().on('metadata', (meta) => { /* any code */ })
```

At least on v0.9.x you can see: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/v1.9.x/packages/grpc-native-core/src/client.js#L562