# GRPC Exception handling

Tags: authentication, .net-core, grpc

I've created a small GRPC service in .NET core. The service has authentication enabled:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
       options.Audience = config["AAD:Audience"];
       options.Authority = config["AAD:Authority"];
    });
```

I've also created a small client, that can connect to the service by adding a Bearer token, and it works fine. However if I call the service withour a token, I get an exception back, with the following message:

```
Status(StatusCode=Cancelled, Detail="Bad gRPC response. Expected HTTP status code 200. Got status code: 401")
```

Is there a (smart) way, to capture this server side and convert it into a GRPC payload, instead of getting an exception on the client??

TIA

Comment: You may have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777189/can-i-send-a-custom-error-message-from-server-to-client-grpc

Comment: I think the situation is a bit different here, since I'm not in control of the Authentication. So somehow I need to intercept the Authorization and return a "normal" GRPC result.

Comment: As stated here, it might be best to just retrun the exception, eventhough its statuscode is cancelled 
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/264